# have or having after preposition with two objects

Tags: gerunds, coordination, infinitive-vs-gerund, parallelism

I'm doubtful whether to use the gerund form or the base form of *have* in the following sentence:

> He's afraid of being debunked in public and **have/having** his reputation ruined.

I would choose *having* as the correct option if I had to, because it acts as the object of the preposition *of*--*He's afraid of being debunked in public and* (consequently, he's afraid of) ***having*** his reputation ruined. However, *have* sounds more natural to me.

Which would be grammatically correct in the context of the example above: *having* or *have*? Is it common to use *have* in these types of sentences in informal speech?

Comment: I think you got it right, grammatically, but I would understand it as he's afraid of one thing: "being debunked in public and (consequently) having his reputation ruined".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> He's afraid of **being** debunked in public **and** have/**having** his reputation ruined.

The coordinating conjunction **and** connects two [gerund-participial clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_clause): "being debunked in public" and "having his reputation ruined". Both are objects of the preposition **of**.

If we use **have** instead of **having**, we will violate the [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) of this construction.

So yes, **having** seems the correct choice.

Your second question,

> Is it common to use have in these types of sentences in informal speech?

..is very interesting. Maybe **being** and **having** clash in some way, and one feels the urge to use **have**? Maybe "being" and "having" make the construction feel non-parallel, and one instinctively tries to remodel the sentence to:

> He's afraid of being debunked in public, **and** also afraid **to** **have** his reputation ruined.

..and this remodeling goes only part of the way in speech, leaving us with

> He's afraid of **being** debunked in public **and** **have** his reputation ruined.

Could it be so? I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not sure. (0:

---

What if we left only **being** in the sentence?

> He's afraid of **being** debunked in public **and** **being** left with his reputation in ruins.

I feel the urge to get rid of the second **being** here:

> He's afraid of **being** debunked in public **and** left with his reputation in ruins.

Now the parallel structures are "debunked in public" and "left with his reputation in ruins", and they hinge not on **of** but on **being**. Maybe because of this ability of **being** to take on parallel structures one can feel that **being** and **having** clash with each other?

Just a conjecture.

Comment: It's my personal take that the parallel format works best as you say. I feel like "afraid of" is also applied to the stuff after "and", so we need "having". The cause and effect nuance is still achieved by "and". My conjecture is that the urge to use "have" stems from the construction "afraid to X and Y", where X,Y are verbal phrases, X is cause and Y is effect.

Comment: Native speaker (American, northeast) perspective: "He's afraid of being debunked in public and have his reputation ruined" sounds quite jarring to me, and it would immediately be recognized as incorrect grammar in speech or writing.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi - a nice observation! It may well be so!

Answer (score 5):

"He is afraid of A and B."  The verbs used in the phrases A and B need to match form, therefore "being" and "have" would be incorrect together, while "being" and "having" would be correct.  Alternatively, "He is afraid he will be debunked in public and have his reputation ruined."

Answer (score 5):

"Having" is the grammatically proper phrase.  Gerunds make the phrase a noun phrase, while the bare verb makes it a verbal phrase, and "afraid of" usually takes a noun phrase. The "and" makes "afraid of" apply to both phrases.

> He's afrad of [noun phrase] and [noun phrase]
>
> He's afraid of being debunked in public and having his reputation ruined

Compare this to "afraid to" which takes a verbal phrase:

> He's afraid to get debunked in public and have his reputation ruined.

I'm not exactly sure why I see the "and" makes it necessary to parallelize the phrases. Also I'd like to note that in this particular case, both seem decently natural, even if not 100% idiomatic. Nobody is going to notice anything odd if they hear these sentences, because they won't notice that you've essentially made the ungrammatical phrase "afraid of have ...".

However, for shorter sentences, it's way worse. For example, one colloquial phrase I've heard a few times is "going and getting".

> Have you thought about going and getting your wisdom teeth removed.

In this case, because the phrase is so short, it's very obvious that "about" is applied to "getting you wisdom teeth removed", so replacing "getting" with "get" would sound very unnatural.